# Cannot enable Huawei Wallet fingerprint verification — "Unable to apply for certificate"

Tags: huawei, internet, cache, certificates

A friend of mine has a Huawei Nova 9 SE and wants to his bank cards in the Wallet app so he could pay directly with the phone.

Every time when we try to add the card, it says we should enter the PIN to enable the Fingerprint verification for payments. Fingerprint unlocking is already enabled and it works.

After entering the PIN, we get the following message:

> `Unable to apply for certificate.`

I tried:

1. Restarting the phone
2. Clearing HMS Core and Wallet cache and data + Phone Restart
3. Having a different Payment PIN from the default Phone PIN
4. Setting the current date/time manually.
5. Switching to Mobile Data, instead of Wifi

None of these worked.

Is there any alternative to Huawei Wallet that we could install and would work smoothly? What is the actual cause of the error?